# Is there a way to have tabs with independent content in them, without extending TabActivity or using fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

Is there a way to have tabs with independent content in them, without extending TabActivity or using fragments?
I am a newbie in android development and I am confused with TabHost and TabView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design support library has a `TabLayout` that you can easily use.

> The Design library’s TabLayout implements both fixed tabs, where the
>   view’s width is divided equally between all of the tabs, as well as
>   scrollable tabs, where the tabs are not a uniform size and can scroll
>   horizontally. Tabs can be added programmatically
>   However, if you are using a ViewPager for horizontal paging between
>   tabs, you can create tabs directly from your PagerAdapter’s
>   getPageTitle() and then connect the two together using
>   setupWithViewPager(). This ensures that tab selection events update
>   the ViewPager and page changes update the selected tab.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
```

With API level 21 , `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` has been depricated in favor of `TabLayout`.

For more, http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Without using fragments? Well, that's not possible. You will have to use a `ViewPager`, make a few `Fragment`s and make a fragment adapter that wires them all up.